# Parsing File to Get List of Names in C#

Tags: c#

I'm parsing my `/etc/passwd` file, which looks like this:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
bin:x:1:1:bin:/bin:/sbin/nologin
daemon:x:2:2:daemon:/sbin:/sbin/nologin
adm:x:3:4:adm:/var/adm:/sbin/nologin
lp:x:4:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/sbin/nologin
sync:x:5:0:sync:/sbin:/bin/sync
```

I want my program to return the following:

```
root
bin
daemon
...
sync
```

My current code is this:

```
Regex expression = new Regex(@"^\w*");
foreach (Match myMatch in expression.Matches(txt))
{
    txtout.Text = myMatch.ToString();    
}
```

But, I'm only returning `root` with this code. How can I return every line?

Comment: if you can't put togther a decent question, how do you expect to get decent answers???

Comment: Zimzim, how do you get 'txt'? Does it contain line breaks?

Comment: Mitch, come on. At least give an indication on what's bordering you, so zimzim can improve the question.

Comment: i get txt fro textbox , user fill

Comment: zimzim, make up your mind. Is it a (multiline) textbox or a file?

Answer (score 5):

Using regex is an overkill, if I understand your intention correctly you want to retrieve the substring before the first `':'` character.

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader ("/etc/passwd")) {
    string line = "";
    while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) {
         string userName = line.Substring(0, line.IndexOf(':'));
    }
}
```

Comment: @arul , i use this but i get this error :
Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface System.IO.TextReader' , i want user fill someStream with textbox ,

Comment: Oops, sorry, wrote the code off the top of my head, now it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the RegexOption that specifies that you want to use multi-line support, you will get every line. I don't know it from the top of my head, I think it's part of the RegexOptions enum.

Regards,

Sebastiaan

Answer (score 0):

You obviously need to loop over each line in the file rather than looking at the contents of the file as a whole (as a string).  Is this Mono?

```
 Regex expression = new Regex(@"^\w*");
 var passwd = new StreamReader( "/etc/passwd" );
 var users = new List<string>();
 while (passwd.Peek() >= 0)
 {
     var line = passwd.ReadLine();
     foreach (Match myMatch in expression.Matches(txt))
     {
         users.Add( myMatch.ToString() );
     }
 }

 // now users will contain all the users in the file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var names = File.ReadAllLines(fileName)
                .Select(line => line.Substring(0, line.IndexOf(':')));
```